# pyglet installation error in anaconda (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyglet

I am getting the following error when I tried to install pyglet:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge pyglet
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pyglet -> python 3.5* -> xz 5.0.5
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to downgrade my pyglet version from 1.3 using "pip install"

```
pip install pyglet==1.2.4
```